# Android NDK cant start debugger due to port connection failure

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk

When trying out the example code in [google code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-cmake/#2). I create a very simple hello world app with NDK components. Compiling and running on the phone were successful.

However, I couldn't start debugging the native code. When I press the `Debug :app` icon, the app shows `Waiting For Debugger` screen, while Android studio got stuck at `Starting LLDB Server...` .After a few minutes, the console output `Failed to connect port`.
[image: Studio Screenshot]

Neither a real phone nor an emulator can successfully start the debug process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to Platform-tools version 29.0.4 solves the problem. Apparently, this problem appears in platform-tools 29.0.3